# what are the tools to parse/analyze IIS logs - ideally free/open source?

Tags: iis, logging

note: there are few similar questions already asked here - but they are from 2009. May be something has changed since then.

I'm responsible for a bunch of websites hosted on different servers. I do not do any log analysis right now, but I would like to change this. First question - what is the best tool to view ISSUES with the website based on IIS logs (i.e. 404, 500 responses, long page processing, etc)? Ideally with grouping/sorting options? I do not want to spend a lot of time on this, I just want to periodically check if all is good with the website.

Second question (and I know most likely i'm asking for too much) - but is there any way to expose processed logs to web? So I can review things mentioned above without RPDing into the server?

Ideally I'm looking for a free/open source solution, but I'm ready to pay for a good software as well (but not a lot of $$).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at our log monitoring solution [EventSentry](http://www.eventsentry.com), which can monitor text-based logs like IIS logs. We have standard templates setup for IIS, and we can consolidate the logs in a database with web-access, so that you can review the logs without using RDP.

It's a pretty flexible solution that allows you to pick the fields you are interested in, and ignore the ones you are not - and thus save space in your database.

You can also setup real-time alerts, so that you can get an email when a critical error is encountered in a log file, like a 500 error.

http://www.eventsentry.com/features/log-file-monitoring

Finally, you can also plug-in command line tools which can verify that a given web page is accessible, or get alerted when it changes: http://www.eventsentry.com/features/application-monitoring.

I'm biased of course, but I would say that our solution is pretty affordable. Since it offers additional functionality as well, such as service monitoring (to monitor your IIS services) and event log monitoring (IIS does log critical messages to the event log), you can setup comprehensive monitoring with a single product.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into @LuckyLuke solution (or similar) - classic "build vs buy" decision. Based on your post, this isn't going to be your "full time" job so IMHO its best to leave it to those who do...

I don't know what "legacy" answers you are referring to, but if you want to tinker you can use Microsoft's own [log parser](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1976), and depending on how far you want to go with it, you can use it (COM dll) to write your "admin web pages" in .Net/ASP.Net and host it in each of your servers....

If you're very specific about the errors you just want to be alerted about, another "hacky" way would be to provide your own custom error pages (either the default IIS error pages, or configure your Asp.Net apps to use specific error pages).